# Definitive method for determining if a container uses a server package or its own

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, docker

My understanding of containerization is limited, so it's possible this question is misguided, but I know for a fact that Docker containers utilize some kernel resources of their host system to remain relatively lightweight. To the best of my knowledge, this can extend to OS distributed packages (e.g. binutils).

Assuming I'm not mistaken in thinking docker containers have the capacity to utilize host provided packages, is there a standard way to enumerate all those packages which the container intends/expects to find on a given server when hosted by it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know for a fact that Docker containers utilize some kernel resources of their host system to remain relatively lightweight.

Yes, containers share the host kernel.

> To the best of my knowledge, this can extend to OS distributed packages (e.g. binutils).

It *can*, but it’s extremely unusual, and requires manual setup outside the container — basically, you need to mount a volume from the host, allowing the container to access the relevant parts of its file system(s).

In the vast majority of cases, containers’ user-space portions are entirely separate from the host. There is no standard way to enumerate packages which the container expects to find on the host, because containers normally have no such expectation and there is no way for them to declare such expectations. If you come across such a container, the documentation should tell you about it, and if it has a deployment descriptor of any kind (*e.g.* a Helm chart for Kubernetes), it will include the required volumes and mount points (but that won’t tell you what it needs from the host).

Containers are really host-agnostic: they run on any system with the appropriate container runtime, and the host can use any package system it wants, or even none at all. So containers don’t even have the necessary concepts to require a package from the host; it would go against some of the fundamental principles behind containers.

Comment: Ah, okay thanks! So, would it be accurate to say that all packages, even ones that are distributed via OS updates (e.g. binutils 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.5) are still firmly in the realm of user-space resources?

If so, I think not knowing that was the source of my confusion.

Comment: Yes, the fact that containers share the host’s kernel only gives them access to the kernel (including any modules loaded) and any mounted pseudo-file systems (`/proc`, `/sys` etc., with the restrictions imposed by namespaces). The only contributing packages are the kernel package and packages installing kernel modules.